# Python: Cyrillic handling

Tags: python, json, string, unicode, cyrillic

I got this data returned `b'\\u041a\\u0435\\u0439\\u0442\\u043b\\u0438\\u043d\\u043f\\u0440\\u043e` from an API. This data is in Russian which I know for sure. I am guessing these values are unicode representation of the cyrillic letters?

The data returned was a byte array.

How can I convert that into readable cyrillic string? Pretty much I need a way to convert that kind into readable human text.

EDIT: Yes this is JSON data. Forgot to mention, sorry.

Comment: Most likely you have **JSON** data.

Comment: Oh yes, forgot to mention it is JSON data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chances are you have JSON data; JSON uses `\uhhhh` escape sequences to represent Unicode codepoints. Use the [`json.loads()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) on *unicode* (decoded) data to produce a Python string:

```
import json

string = json.loads(data.decode('utf8'))
```

UTF-8 is the default JSON encoding; check your response headers (if you are using a HTTP-based API) to see if a different encoding was used.

Demo:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads(b'"\\u041a\\u0435\\u0439\\u0442\\u043b\\u0438\\u043d\\u043f\\u0440\\u043e"'.decode('utf8'))
'Кейтлинпро'
```

Comment: Ahh wonderful. I understand. I was getting a like freaked out thinking there is like a unique way to handle non-ascii chars.